# Custom json contractresolver .net web api falling back to camelcase in some cases

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

in an asp.net web api I would like to serialize my C# properties (pascal case) in a way that any property whose name is "Links" should be serialized to "_links" and the rest should be serialized to itself in camel casing.

So far I have this code

```
public class MyCustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == "Links")
        {
            return "_links";
        }
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

And using this in the WebApiConfig's Register's method

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new MyCustomResolver();
```

I manage to serialize Links to _links. In order to "camel-case" the rest of the properties I could try one of the methods that are in the web for achieving that in C# string but I was wondering if there's a way of just use the in built Json.net **CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver** which I guess should be better tested for all scenerarios. And I can't figure out how

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was quite obvious but yesterday I couldn't see it. Shame on me. The custom resolver instead of inheriting from **DefaultContractResolver** should inherit from **CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver** and then we can call the base method

```
public class MyCustomResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName == "Links" ? "_links" : base.ResolvePropertyName(propertyName);
    }
}
```