# Replace OData default Json serializer with newtonSoft's Json Serializer

Tags: json, json.net, odata, jsonserializer

I'm re-writing a project and decided to use .NetCore with AspNetCore.OData (V: 7.4.1).
the default Odata serializer makes it hard to both define function and actions on an object (which requires it to be registered as entitySet) **and** serialize it as a part of a larger-scoped object (which requires it to be registered as complexType).
is there a way to override odata's default serilizer with newtonsoft's and that way avoid having to register unnecessary ComplexTypes?
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353775/how-do-i-replace-the-odata-v4-default-json-serializer-with-newtonsofts-json-ser) from 4 years ago and figured thing have changed.

Comment: Not sure I agree with it being hard to define functions and actions, certainly verbose though. What have you tried and what element is causing you trouble. In short you can't easily replace the OData serializer, but there are shortcuts to some issues.